# Get the request URL in HTML::Mason

Tags: perl, mason

How we can find the GET request URL in a perl website using HTML::Mason. I have tried using $m object from Mason.

Comment: You will have better chances if you show what you have done so far.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In addition to the `$m` Mason request object you also have `$r` the Apache request object.  The `uri` method will return the path component of the requested URL:

```
my $url = $r->uri;
```

You can read more in the [Mason Developer's Manual](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/HTML-Mason/lib/HTML/Mason/Devel.pod#Request-Objects).

If you want the requested URL including the query string, you can use the `unparsed_uri` method:

```
my $url_with_qs = $r->unparsed_uri;
```

You can read more in the [mod_perl documentation for Apache2::RequestRec](https://metacpan.org/pod/Apache2::RequestRec).

Comment: At least the requets method only return the path poretion of the URL, not the actual URL.